# How to find if a word exists in a very large file in an optimized way ?

Tags: java, string, search, random

The game goes like this:
The player inputs a number of vowels in [0..10].
We generate 10-input(vowels) consonants to finally display 10 letters unordered.
The player then tries to form the longest word possible with the given letters.

The problem:
we have a dictionary of important size to go through to find if the word is valid.

What is the best way to search through it? 
My best two ideas are:

1. Seperate the word in different files indexed by the number of vowels inside the words stored in it.
2. Use `Streamer()`. filter method using a function that returns the number of vowels in a word.

Both seem very expensive in term of time complexity (i don't know if im using the term correctly).

I hope i was clear enough.

Comment: Your title is very large and unspecific, better find another ;)

Comment: You could start with `HashSet<String>`

Comment: How large ? How many words ?

Comment: @Ivan is right, you can just stick them in a HashSet and look them up in constant time. Even the largest English dictionaries with all plurals and conjugations will trivially fit in memory. If your data set had been larger (1GB+) with frequent lookups, the standard technique is a Bloom filter for coarse filtering and a pre-indexed file (e.g. with sqllite).

Comment: @Ivan how do i fill a HashSet<String> with words from a file ? with a condition on words no longer than 10 letters?

Comment: @emnamokhtar this is how to read from file https://howtodoinjava.com/core-java/io/java-read-file-to-string-examples/

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you are using java. If that is true you can store all your words inside a `HashSet<String>`.

Sets store data in buckets. So when you search for a word, jvm would first find a bucket which might have this word and then look into that bucket to confirm if that word is present or not.

This approach is similar to the option 1 you have mentioned. All the complexity is hidden from you. you just need to call the contains method. jvm does all this for you behind the scene.

```
    HashSet<String> dictionary = new HashSet<String>();

    //add words to dictionary
    dictionary.add("apple");

    //Returns true if this set contains the specified element. 
    dictionary.contains("apple");
```